# How to calculate zoom or mapScale for an array of coordinates using ArcGIS sdk for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, arcgis, esri

I need to calculate mapScale or zoom for a set of AGSGraphics (Restaurants or Known places) to show them in map. 
I have searched in google and stack-overflow, but I did not find any solution.

I have added all the graphics to AGSGraphicOverlay and I am able to see all of them in map while running. But I want to show few of the graphics so that every graphic can fit in screen bounds.

I am able to show those few graphics in map by using below steps.

=> Calculated minimum coordinate and maximum coordinate and converted them as AGSPoint

=> Created AGSEnvelope using these min and max Points

=> Created AGSViewPoint with that AGSEnvelope

=> Able to show in map using **mapView?.setViewPoint(...)**

If user clicks on any Graphic, I am showing all the details of that graphic in a UIView which is having size of 300x200. This customView was added to the map using **AGSMapView.addSubView** method. For every 2 minutes I need to show next restaurant or a known place along with the previous checked in users location (users can be any number and so I need to show all of those locations by making the restaurant as center).

After doing all this I am getting an issue, which is I am not able to show my UIView fully with a padding of 30 pixel which will show all the details of that restaurant. To resolve this issue I need to calculate a zoom level and then I can use the API of **AGSViewpoint(center: point, scale: mapScale)**

Can anybody please refer me any links or explain me how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'setViewPoint'. Because you should take geometry envelop andd zoom this geometry. You should give it a padding envelope.

```
self.mapView.setViewpointGeometry(polygoneGeometryEnvelope, padding: 75, completion: nil)
```

https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/latest/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_polyline.html